# Swapping images in Bootstrap for different screen sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display one large image for regular screens and ipads and then drop down to a smaller image, an actual different image not scaled, when in mobile screen. How can I achieve this with just css and html and bootstrap (no JS). Is there a way? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a kinda hacky method involving `background-image` and media queries:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-backgrounds/

(See the full article for the additional details needed for a production-ready battle-tested version.)

It boils down to:

```
#image { 
  background-image: url(your-large-image.jpg); 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { // change/add media queries as necessary
  #image { 
    background-image: url(your-small-image.jpg); 
  }
}
```

---

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

---

There's also the [`<picture>` element](http://picture.responsiveimages.org/) and the [`srcset` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/srcset/w3c-srcset/), but neither of those are fully standardized or widely supported at this time.

You might be best served by dropping the "no JavaScript" requirement and using something like [Interchange](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html).